# Этимология слова "ликование"

Tags: этимология

"Ликование" - огромная всеобщая (как правило) радость. А это вообще русское слово? Какое у него происхождение?
Заранее благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ЛИКОВАТЬ — слово заимствовано из ст.-сл. языка, это суф. производное от "ликъ" — пение, праздник, пляски.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Этимология  слова  "лик" в целом неясная. Предполагается о.-с. основа *likъ* и *lice* (лицо), а также и.-е. база со значением изгибать, гнуть. Соответственно, даются  разные значения для слова "лик", в частности:

а) танец, праздник, ликование, ликующая толпа, сравнить из гот. *laiks* "танец", *laikan* "скакать, прыгать";
б) лицо, изображение лица на иконе.

Answer (score 4):

ОЧЕНЬ ИНТЕРЕСНЫЙ ВОПРОС!
Я попытался найти ответ на него с помощью "Полного церковно-славянского словаря", составленного магистром Григорием Дьяченко. Отрываем страницу 283-ю (*вот интернет-ссылка*: [link text](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0283.htm)) и узнаем, что **Ликъ** — это не только изображение лица, но также и **собрание поющих и пляшущих**, и **песнь, сопровождаемая пляскою**, и, что очень интересно, ещё и в значении **хоровод**.
На этой же странице (чуть выше) читаем : **Ликовникъ, ликовственникъ... = участникЪ въ хороводе**, а также **Ликонаставникъ, ликоучитель = предводитель хоровода**.
На этой же странице слово **Лик(овств)ую** — в словосочетании **окрестъ ликую** — означает **танцую около чего**.
Таким образом, получается, что корень **ЛИК-**, помимо физиономии, связан с *радостным танцем*, с *пляской*. Просто этот *танцеозначающий* аспект данного корня был забыт, и сохранилось только понятие *радости* .